# Jersey Path Param : Multiple backslash separated param

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, path-parameter

```
@Path("/assetViewCount/{path}")
```

above annotation can be used to retrive *myValue* into *path* for url like /assetViewCount/myValue.

How can I get ***myValue/nextValue*** from ***/assetViewCount/myValue/nextValue*** in path

Comment: Could you provide some real-world examples? Are you trying to find to return the `assetViewCount` of 2 different `things`. Is there some relationship between the 2 values?

Comment: not two different things, basically this ${path} can be a file path something like myFolder/subFolder/myFile.ext

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution to my problem, following annotation gives whatever there is after /assetViewCount/ into {path}

```
@Path("/assetViewCount/{path:.*}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embedded parameter in Path like this:

```
@Path("/assetViewCount/{path}/nextValue")
```

Comment: for the url like, /assetViewCount/myValue/nextValue, it will give me myValue in {path}, but what i am expecting is whatever comes after /assetViewCount into {path}

Comment: It really needs to be `@Path("/assetViewCount/{path}/{nextValue}")`